# hive:command not found in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hive

I have installed hive in ubuntu , followed all the steps from the article http://www.edureka.co/blog/apache-hive-installation-on-ubuntu/

I have set HADOOP_HOME,HIVE_HOME.

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ echo $HADOOP_HOME
/usr/local/hadoop
hduser@ubuntu:~$ echo $HIVE_HOME
/usr/local/hive
```

I have mentioned HADOOP_HOME under hive-config.sh file .

when I ran hive command I got an error :

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hive/bin$ hive
hive: command not found
```

Am I missing something? Please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are in /usr/local/hive/bin, you'll have to execute

./hive

to run it. This tells your shell to look in the local directory instead of using $PATH.

To permanently add hive to $PATH, run the following command:

export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin

and add that to your .profile

Answer (score 0):

no need to worry :-

just need to check two files :-

1. `~/.bashrc`  2.`hive/bin/hive-config.sh`

for `~/.bashrc` :- 
in command prompt :- type :-

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

add below lines at the end

```
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop/apache-hive-0.13.0      
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
```

CTRL + X

then

`source ~/.bashrc` ( this command will save and implement the above settings into your environment)

for file 2 . :-

at the end of file `hive/bin/hive-config.sh`

add below lines :-

`export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop`   ( instaed of HADOOP_INSTALL , use HADOOP_HOME , as HADOOP_INSTALL is my variable in my bashrc file)

save file.

In command prompt type

```
hive
```

and u will get below :-

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/apache-hive-0.13.0/lib/hive-common-0.13.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
hive>
```

cheers .....

Comment: I've followed the same steps you followed, then why i'm getting the following [error](https://pastebin.com/zZzHqy00), please urgent help needed.